# Can these Chinese cameras be used as webcams?

Tags: usb, webcam, compatibility, camera

There are many cameras sourced from China that seem to be rebrands of the same item. A mere sample of Amazon links includes
[SJCAM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078SS1RND)
[AKASO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HGM33HG)
[Campark](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MXXP4EC)
[COOAU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DWP3M46).

There are many more. I don't know what electronics are in them, but they sure appear to at least use the same enclosure and lens.

There is [one Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611664/sjcam-sj4000-not-recognised-by-pc/656976#656976) already, which seems to indicate that this type of camera worked in a previous version, but no longer does.

What I would like to do is use the USB3 cable to connect such a camera to my PC and use it as a webcam. None of these inexpensive cameras are listed in the gphoto database of Linux-compatible cameras.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit: another [existing Ask Ubuntu question about the same camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062440/webcam-not-recoginized-on-18-04).

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to acheive and why?

Comment: @Simplexion, I want to use this external camera as a high-resolution webcam, to stream using various web conferencing/streaming applications, e. g. Discord.

Comment: If they work as webcams with Windows, they're likely to work as well in Ubuntu, regardless of the gphoto database which, by the way, is not related to webcams. And no, those GoPro clones aren't designed to work as webcams and neither is the original GoPro.

Comment: They are not GoPro clones per se, @GabrielaGarcia. They're certainly GoPro imitators, though. As I say, another user of this site reported using one as a webcam. They're so cheap I think I will pick one up and test it.

Comment: A correction to the previous comment: SJCAM has indeed a USB webcam mode. Don't know about the others. How high the resolution is with generic drivers (Windows or Ubuntu) I'm not sure. But yes, they're so cheap that you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in fact buy one, and it works fine as a webcam on my box, at full resolution and frame rate. Also mounts as an external (MTP) drive perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It can vary. Some simply do have PC cam functionality. I have an Akaso Brave 7 LE, which will stream in PC cam mode at 720, and an Apeman 87 which does so at 1080